# Is &#xe877; a valid unicode character? (Done all icon)

Tags: unicode

According to this page `&#xe877;` looks like a valid unicode character:

> https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_google-done_all

But I am unsure, since I can't find more infos about this "done all" symbol.

Is this a valid unicode character?

Comment: And if you study the "try it" HTML in question, you'll notice that it is using CSS that refers to a custom [Material Icons](https://material.io/icons/) font provided by Google. That font has the "done all" glyph for U+E877.

Comment: @Biffen thank you for your comment. If you write it as answer, then I will upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s [valid](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=E877)<sup>*</sup>, but it’s in the private use area.

It’s not uncommon<sup>†</sup> to see private use characters together with custom fonts (so called *icon fonts*) to make ‘icons’.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup>For some definition of ‘valid’: It shouldn’t be used unless you have control over how it will be rendered.</sup>

<sup><sup>†</sup>[But arguably controversial. ️](https://youtu.be/9xXBYcWgCHA)</sup>